# Random Season Generator

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm a newcomer to coding and I am having some difficulties. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? Thanks in advance. I am trying to assign each summer to a number between 1-4 but it is not working. I think my conditional statements may be off.

```
function randomSeason() {
    var s = prompt("Enter a number between one and four");
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 ) ;
    var x= ""; 
    if  (r===1) ; 
        x=" fall";
    alert(" It's fall");
    "else if"; (r===2);  { 
           x =" spring";
        alert(" It's spring") ; 

    } 
      "else"; }
    if (r===3); 
        x="winter";
  alert(" It's winter!"); {

  }
  "else if"; ( r===4); 
  alert(" It's summer!"); 
 { 
alert(r);  

}
```

Comment: Why are you putting "else if" and "else" in quotes?

Comment: Have you tried google if-else statements?

Comment: Also you should learn when to use " ; " in your code

Comment: I understand your new, but I'm not sure why you think this would work. It's quite clear you just guessed the syntax without looking it up, if you don't know how to make an `if-elseif-else` statement in JavaScript don't just guess, google it before attempting.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
function randomSeason() {
    var s = prompt("Enter a number between one and four");
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1);
    var x= ""; 
    if (r===1){
        x="fall";
        alert("It's fall");
    }else if(r===2){ 
        x ="spring";
        alert("It's spring"); 
    }else if(r===3){
        x="winter";
        alert("It's winter!"); 
    }else if(r===4){
        x="summer";
        alert("It's summer!"); 
    }else{
        alert(r);
    } 
}
```

I encourage you to read [how to write if...else statement in Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp).

Comment: so what is the prompt() for ?

Comment: you are correct, actually I don't know why OP put that line in the code!!

Answer (score 0):

`r` will always be between `0-3` because you are using `Math.floor`.
Three ways to fix that:

1. Use `Math.ceil` instead of `Math.floor`
2. Add +1 to the result of `Math.floor`
3. Adjust your conditions by using 0-3 instead of 1-4

Answer (score -1):

```
var seasons = ['spring', 'summer', 'fall', 'winter'];
var which = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);

alert('It\'s ' + seasons[which] + '!');
```

Comment: How does this help? It's a code snippet with no context nor does it explain the problems in OP's code. Along with that this doesn't attempt to answer the question.

Comment: He's trying to generate a random season. My answer shows a very simple way to do that.

Comment: Yes he is, but the question is *"Can anyone tell me what is wrong with **my code**?"*. Sure they can copy this completely separate code snippet and it will work without knowing what they did wrong, but it's not really answering OP's question.